# C# - NullReferenceException points to path that doesn't exist

Tags: c#, .net, odbc

I'm facing an strange problem with one of my applications, written in C# with .NET 4.8.1 (WPF) suddenly throws a NullRefrenceException when trying to initialize the application.

**The Environment**

The environment in which my application is running is the following:

- Windows 10 21H2
- .NET-Frameworks installed from 3.5 to the current .NET 6
- Access-file as database
- Selfdeveloped MVVM-Framework

**The Problem:**

The application itself is located at the local workstation of my customer. The needed database (an access-database) is located at a netshare with the assigned drive "U:".

This configuration was never changed, and worked since 2017. The application also never changed since 2021.

Since a few days, the application can't start. The Inner Exception of the thrown Exception says the following:

```
Inner Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: An invocation target threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for "MVVM.Framework.Locator.ObjectLocator" threw an exception. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: An invocation target threw an exception. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MyApplication.ViewModel.ViewModel..ctor() in F:\MyApplication\Application.cs:line 1028.
   at MyApplication.ViewModel.ViewModel..ctor() in F:\MyApplication\Application.cs:line 1013.
```

I know, that the ObjectLocator, who loads the ViewModels can't find the ViewModel.cs-Files because it searches under the drive "F:". And that result's into a null reference, because the path doesn't exist.

And that's the part, where I'm stuck - the Project-Files (Visual Studio Solution, etc..) are stored on my local PC on the drive F: - the path inside the exception is identical with the path where the original cs-Files are lying (ergo my development folder).

The thing is, locally on my workstation it works fine. I've also tested it with two other machines (same Windows build as the customer's workstation) and also with the database-files lying under an netshare with letter "U:". And that's also working fine without errors.

So i'm not sure where my application might get that path to search for loading .cs-files, because technically and physically the path doesn't exist on the customer's workstation.

My first thought was, that maybe the environment at the customer's workstation changed. I've talked to the local it-administrator and the only thing that was changed was the installation of the windows update KB5017380 on all machines. But it also runs on my workstations with that specific update installed. :-(

**What we've tried so far:**

- Changing the Drive-letter at the customer's workstation from U: to F: including the complete folder-structure: resulted into an odbc-error: `ERROR [HY024][MICROSOFT][ODBC MICROSOFT ACCESS DRIVER]'(unknown)' is not a valid path.`
- Checking the *.settings & *.config-Files if any of the Variables contains a path to "F:": All paths are correct and pointing to the drive "U:"
- We've checked if the user has the correct rights to access the local application folder and the netshare containing the databases
- We've checked the paths at the local odbc-connections also
- I've searched my entire application for that path to ensure it is not hardcoded in any part of my source code
- We've installed the tool on an other workstation of the customer and configured it identically like the other. The tool doesn't start and throws the same error.

Maybe somebody knows a hint, because i'm don't know where the application could get that path information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This may be a credential issue.  The app cannot read the folder.

Comment: Hi @jdweng we've tried that too. The credentials are correct, all users can access the database-files on the netshare.

Comment: The driver is not setup.  From Start button in Windows type : ODBC Data Sources (32 bit).  There is a driver that is not installed or the entry is missing from the odbc data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were able to solve the issue.
The NullReferenceException was correct, but the path inside the exception pointing to the .cs-File was an issue of the pdb-File. It only pointed out the file in which the error occured.

My application has an internal eventlog, we've checked it and it came out that a subfunction of the cs-File mentioned in the NullReferenceException was not working correctly due to a faulty value in the coresponding database column.

We fixed the column and voila - it runs like charm!

The error i've posted was correct, but the path made doubts and guided us away from the real problem.

Thanks to all users who have participated on this journey of debugging. :)